# left and right aligned text with different page layouts

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, tabs, headers, alignment

I want to make my template in Word 2010 as simple as possible for users. At the moment in the footer there is some text left aligned then a right tab stop for the page numbers. My issue is when I turn the page to landscape it uses the same tab stop instead of aligning to the right of the page (obviously). Is there a way that I can set the footer up so that it works in landscape and portrait? ie. Will left align the text and right align the page numbers automatically in both landscape and portrait page set-up.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

There is an elegant solution available: Alignment tabs.

In the header or footer, type your left-margin-aligned text as you normally would. When you are ready to align text with the right margin (say, to insert a page number or date), click on "Insert Alignment Tab" in the "Position" section of the "Header&Footer Tools" menu on the Ribbon at the top of the screen.

Select "right" alignment relative to the margin. This will align your cursor with the right margin. Add any text you would like here.

Since this text is aligned relative to the right margin, it will automatically adjust when you insert landscaped pages.

Answer (score 0):

Right-align the page number (e.g., with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, no <kbd>Tab</kbd>s) and insert a text box near the left margin.

[image: Microsoft Word footer with left-aligned text box and right-aligned page number field]